# change background color of ionic 2 tabs

Tags: ionic2

I know that using the following changes the icon color of my Tabs buttons when active:

```
$tabs-ios-tab-icon-color-active: red;
```

But I don't see how to change the background-color of the button when active.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

@cnak2, looking at https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/src/components/tabs/tabs.ios.scss, you can see the background color is set by the variable $tabs-ios-background.
I suggest changing this variable to include the color you would like to see.

Answer (score 0):

In general go to [this page](http://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/overriding-ionic-variables/) to determine the sass variables for customization.

if you search "tab" you will see `$tabs-background` show up which is probably the one you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this , you change color on directory `src/theme/variables.scss`

```html
<ion-tabs color="primary">
    <ion-tab [root]="homeRoot" tabTitle="Home" tabIcon="home"></ion-tab>
    <ion-tab [root]="homeRoot" tabTitle="Home" tabIcon="home"></ion-tab>
    <ion-tab [root]="homeRoot" tabTitle="Home" tabIcon="home"></ion-tab>
    <ion-tab [root]="homeRoot" tabTitle="Home" tabIcon="home"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

Comment: Thanks Muhammad, but I'm trying to change the background color of an individual tab and not the entire block.

Comment: i see, just open google chrome and browse to `chrome://inspect` and make sure your devices connected to usb to live debug via inspect element browser and find component what you want to change .

With this way , you may add separate class each ion-tab component , and find component css class on inspect element session using chrome , and then customize to `pagefolder/pagename.scss` file